# How to add hindi font in wysyiwyg editor magento

Tags: wysiwyg, hindi

I want to add hindi font in WYSIWYG editor for product description in magento. Can someone please help me for this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through below link

http://blog.emagenio.com/?p=7